# How check if an Attribute(object) is null in Java

Tags: java, object, null, parent-child

I need specific data for a report, then I gettin all information from a parent object

`Object1`

It has many attributes, object attributes

`Object11, Object12, Object13, attr1, attr2...`

The attributes has many attributes too

`Object111, Object131, Object132,..`

by now I got 5 level data attributes.

When I send information to my report it says, Error: cause:null

`object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111().getDescription;`

It trows error because Object111 is null

I tried using

`object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111().getDescription==null?'':object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111().getDescription;`

but it only verify if description is null, and throws the same error
Then I tried to verify Object

```
if(object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111() == null) {
    var = object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111().getDescription;
} else {
    var = "";
}
```

But when Object11 is null, it throws same error.

I don't think its a good way doing this for each attribute (have to get like 30 attributes)

```
if(object1.getIdObject11()!=null) {
    if(object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111()!=null) {
        if(object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111().getIdObject1111()!=null) {
             //...
         }
    }
}
```

I want to verify if is there a null object and set '' (blank) if it is, with no such a large code(because the gotten params are set inside a report, mixed with letter).

`reportline1 = "Area: "+object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111().getName;`

Comment: You need to redesign your code and make it more modular. Then you will be able to stream your layout through some method that does the checking. Its hard to give you concrete details if you do not provide your full structure.

Comment: Sorry for not provide it, I'm working on a virtual machine with no copy permision, and its a huge structure.

Comment: Do you mean, put a method on each object, then verify with it?

Comment: No, i mean changing your structure in a way that you can simply loop over all objects in question and thus do this with a couple of lines only. But it is way to broad to get more concrete here. For example, why are there even so many objects floating around instead of being in some collection etc.

Comment: reflection with recursion may help here I think

Comment: Thank you @Zabuza, but App is huge, and its difficult to structure into another way(and, actually its on test phase).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code breaks [Demeter's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). That's why it's better to refactor the design itself. 
As a workaround, you can use `Optional`

```
   var = Optional.ofNullable(object1)
    .map(o -> o.getIdObject11())
    .map(o -> o.getIdObject111())
    .map(o -> o.getDescription())
    .orElse("")
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would probably do this to extend the functionality of the code easily in the future might take a bit of writing in the beginning but will be easily usable forever.

I would create a new method in your parent class called `hasNull` that returns a `boolean` like so:

```
public boolean hasNull()
{
    boolean hasANull = false;

    //Call another hasNull() inside of object11 which in turns calls hasNull() in object111 etc.

    //If any of the calls return with a true/null value set hasANull to true
    return hasANull;  
}
```

This in turn checks to see if the current objects it contains are `null`.  If one of the class variables is another custom class you created you can then add another `hasNull` into that one and keep going until you get to the lowest level where you can do a specific operation when the value is `null` such as set it to `""`.

After implementing this you will be able to just be able to use it like this any time you need it:

```
if (!object1.hasNull())
{
//Do whatever you want if there are no null values
}
else
{
//Do whatever you want if there is a null value
}
```

You can also make this a `void` method if you only want it to toggle the values on the lowest level, and do not need to do anything in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the solution that gave dehasi.

But you can also do something like that:

```java
getOrElse(() -> object1.getIdObject11().getIdObject111().getDescription(), "")
```

Where `getOrElse` is:

```java
public static <T> T getOrElse(Supplier<T> getter, T elseValue) {
    try {
        return getter.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log or do something with it
    }
    return elseValue;
}
```

It may be controversial becaouse you use Exception to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if your object has a null attribute, the object is `myclass`;

```
for (Field f : myclass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    if (Objects.isNull(f.get(myclass))) {
                        isLineContainsNull = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                }
     }
```